# Getting month by Index, Swift?

Tags: swift, calendar

I'm trying to extract month array from Gregorian Calendar.
Extracting weekday is easily done by following method.

```
public static func getWeekDay(_ dayIndex: Int) -> String {
    Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).weekdaySymbols[dayIndex]
} // dayIndex 0 will return Sun
```

But this time I want to do the same for Month. I'm expecting an array like this `["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", .... "Dec"]`. But all I got is `"M01"` , `"M02"`.... etc.

```
po Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).monthSymbols
▿ 12 elements
  - 0 : "M01"
  - 1 : "M02"
  - 2 : "M03"
  - 3 : "M04"
  - 4 : "M05"
  - 5 : "M06"
  - 6 : "M07"
  - 7 : "M08"
  - 8 : "M09"
  - 9 : "M10"
  - 10 : "M11"
  - 11 : "M12"
```

It goes the same for `standaloneMonthSymbols` and `shortMonthSymbols`.
And `veryShortStandaloneMonthSymbols` returns ["1", "2", "3", "4" ..., "12].
Any Idea for ["Jan", "Feb", "Dec"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`monthSymbols` will return a list of months in the calendar, ***localized to the Calendar’s locale***. By default, Calendars have no locale set. If you wish to receive a localized answer, be sure to set the locale.

```
public func getMonths() -> [String] {
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    cal.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return cal.monthSymbols
}
```

```
print(getMonths()) // -> ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

If u want short month symbols use `return cal.shortMonthSymbols`.

**Update** :

If you use `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` it will always return the result in a English as mentioned above. Using `Locale.current` instead of that will return a localized output for users depend on where they are.

eg :  Assume a scenario where `Lacale.current = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")`, then the result would be -> `["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", .......`

Comment: Why `en_US_POSIX`? Why not `Locale.current`?

Comment: You can. But the result would change. For example assume a scenario  where ```Lacale.current = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")```, then the result would be -> ```["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", ......```.

Comment: Exactly. And users of the app in France would be happier. :)

Comment: yeah it depends on the scenario. But ur suggestion is better .  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @HangarRash, it depends on project requirement.

Comment: @ZinWinHtet Absolutely.